# Integration between Ionic, NodeJS, Python and MySQL in Data Analysis

Tags: python, node.js, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I am new to Data Analysis application development. Here is my situation:

> I'm developing an Ionic application (Android, iOS and Web Browser) where NodeJS as it's back-end server. I'm using Python for data analysis and the datasets are in MySQL. I am planning to display the results back in my application in the form of a map for example.

So, how can I display the data to my Ionic application from my data analysis parts in Python including the prediction model and the result?

Answer (score 0):

Communication between an Ionic app and a Node.js server is as simple as calling API from front-end to back-end.

> You can use $http module to call APIs.

For the communication between Python and Node.js, You can use child processes.

> You can spawn a child process to do data analysis and when any output
>   is present the flush it to standard output from python which you can
>   get in Node.js code and hence send it to front-end(Ionic).

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let childP = spawn('python', ['data.analysis.py']);

childP.stdout.on('data', bufferData => {
    // convert bufferData to utf-8
    // bufferData is std output from python
});
```